# Obter apenas 1 de cada jornada

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Bom, tenho uma tabela designada por `tabelajornadas`.

Nela, tenho vários registos, e no qual tenho a coluna `jornada`, que é do tipo `int`.

Na mesma, contêm vários registos com o mesmo número na coluna jornada.

O que pretendo fazer é um `select`, que me dê apenas 1 registo de cada jornada, por ordem crescente de jornada.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Como você não descreveu como está modelado a(s) tabela(s) que deseja ajuda, para você selecionar *apenas um registro com o mesmo número de jornada* faça:

```
SELECT param1, param2, param3 FROM myTable WHERE jornada = "minhaJornada" ORDER BY param1 ASC LIMIT 1
```

Dessa forma, você estará selecionando *param1, param2, param3* da tabela *myTable* onde a *coluna jornada* é igual a uma *jornada especificada* - qual está sendo *ordenada de forma ascendente pelo param1* e *limitando a busca a somente **um** resultado* - exatamente como está descrito em sua dúvida.

Comment: Isto, não está a funcionar, o que pretendo é 1 resultado de cada jornada. Isto só me está a mostrar 1 resultado da primeira jornada.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e por favor, coloque como está montado a sua tabela. Com base nisso, editarei a minha resposta.

Comment: E baseado em `Ou seja se na tabela, tenho 50 registos, com o mesmo numero de jornada, quero que me mostre apenas 1.` - a minha resposta está correta.

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` para checar se existem códigos maiores que o atual para a jornada específica:

```
SELECT tj.*
  FROM tabelajornadas tj
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabelajornadas tj2
                   WHERE tj2.jornada = tj.jornada
                     AND tj2.codigo < tj.codigo)
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa é agrupar os registros. Então pode usar a cláusula `GROUP BY`. Segue um exemplo baseado em seu schema:

```
SELECT
    jornada
FROM
    tabelajornadas
GROUP BY
    jornada
ORDER BY
    jornada;
```

O `GROUP BY` agrupa o resultado pelas colunas que você informar. Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp